# Wordpress - wp_enqueue_style is adding the style to the footer, not the header

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to add styles and scripts to my plugin so I use:

```
function add_my_scripts() {
    wp_register_script( 'test_scripts', plugins_url('test_scripts.js', __FILE__) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'test_scripts' );
}

add_my_scripts();
```

in my plugin page but it adds the script to the footer rather than inside the  tags. The same thing happens with wp_enqueue_style. I read that it's supposed to add the script or style to the head by default. I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: As of WP 3.3, calling wp_enqueue_style mid-page causes styles to load in the footer. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style for reference.

Answer (score 3):

Possible cause:  `wp_head()` is missing from the header or is in the wrong place or somehow isn't getting called.  Are other scripts loading in head correctly?

Also, did you try passing 'false' as the last parameter to `enqueue_script()` to force it to go in the header?  This really shouldn't fix the problem, but it would be something I'd try if I couldn't figure something else out.

Comment: Also, where is your add_my_scripts() function defined an executed?  Is it in a plugin or a theme functions.php file or somewhere else?

Comment: The jquery script appears in the head tag and its loading correctly. I tried using the wp_head action hook to echo some text in the head of the document but when I checked the source, the text wasn't there. I also tried wp_head('echo "TEXT";') but it didn't do anything. I just tried adding FALSE as the last parameter but it didn't work.

Comment: So you're saying you tested this?

somefunction() { echo "test";}
add_action('wp_head', 'somefunction');

That's the correct way to add a function to be called when wp_head() executes.  If you tried that and nothing was output, then something very bizarre is happening... like a plugin that is breaking everything... or some code you wrote doing it.  Did you try what I just asked using a test function?

Comment: I figured out what the problem is. I was calling the add_my_scripts() function from within another function in the plugin PHP file. I tried calling the function at the start of the PHP file instead and now it works. To clarify, I have a main function for my plugin and I'm calling this main function by entering PHP code into the wordpress editor (I had to install a plugin to enable PHP in the editor). Obviously this is a bad approach.

Comment: You're probably talking about PHPExec plugin.  It uses php's exec() function.  Some folks consider it a security hole.  Some hosts (like ZippyKid) disable exec() entirely because they see it as too much of a problem.   How dangerous it really is depends on what other holes you have.

Comment: The technically "better" approach to what you're doing would be to add a META variable to the page you're working with.  In the page template file write a bit of PHP to load the post META data and check for the presence and value of the META variable.  If the variable is there and set to the right value, then do execute your lengthy php function.  Define the lengthy function in another included file to keep the page template clean.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm gonna get rid of this PHP Execution plugin and use another approach. I'm looking into meta variables at the moment. What would I add to the HTML editor to make one of these meta variables?

Comment: I suppose I can make a custom BBCode type tag like [meta]function1[/meta] then use the wp-content action hook to parse that tag. I'd prefer an easier approach though, can you elaborate on these meta variables you mentioned.

Comment: Never mind, I just found out about the add_shortcode() function, thats obviously the way to do what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I spoke too soon. The problem is still there. I need to be able to call these en_queue functions from within a function because otherwise, every single wordpress page will load them because the plugin PHP file is loaded in every page.